# EasyMock void method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, easymock

I'm trying to use EasyMock to mock out some database interface so I can test the business logic off a wrapping method. I've been going ok with methods that return by using the following in my setup of my test.

```
DBMapper dbmapper = EasyMock.createMock(DBMapper.class);
userService.setDBMapper(dbmapper);
```

then within my actual test I run

```
EasyMock.expect(dbmapper.getUser(userId1)).andReturn(mockUser1);
EasyMock.replay(dbmapper);
userService.getUser(userId1);
```

This service then connects to the dbmapper and returns the object (the mapper is injected using setter methods)

These type of mocks seem to work fine. However when I try to run a test for

```
userService.addUser(newUser1);
```

This method calls a void method.

```
dbmapper.createUser(newUser);
```

It's this method that I'm having problems mocking out.
I've tried the following

```
EasyMock.expectLastCall();
EasyMock.replay(dbMapper);
userService.addUser(newUser1);
```

as some other posts/questions etc seem to suggest I get an `IlligalStateException: no last call on a mock available`

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: In case, someone is here because he/she was trying to expect a different behavior for a mock than from the init/before behavior. You might need to add reset(mockObject) before expect().

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're close.

You just need to call the method on your mock before calling `expectLastCall()`

So you expectation would look like this:

```
userService.addUser(newUser1);
EasyMock.expectLastCall();
EasyMock.replay(dbMapper);
userService.addUser(newUser1);
```

This works because the mock object is in Record mode before the call to `replay()`, so any calls to it will perform default behaviour (return null/do nothing) and will be eligible for replaying when the `replay()` method is called.

What I like to do to make sure that it is obvious the method call is for an expectation is to put a small comment in front of it like this:

```
/* expect */ userService.addUser(newUser1);
EasyMock.expectLastCall();
EasyMock.replay(dbMapper);
userService.addUser(newUser1);
```

Comment: Actually, `expectLastCall` is not required for void methods. So, unless `createUser` is final, the following code will work:
    DBMapper dbmapper = EasyMock.createMock(DBMapper.class);
    expect(dbmapper.getUser(userId1)).andReturn(mockUser1);
    dbmapper.createUser(newUser);
    replay(dbmapper);
    userService.addUser(newUser1);

Comment: @Henri Very true. I left it in for completeness.

Comment: In my case, I needed to call `verify(userService)` at the end to verify if the void method is actually called. I am using `EasyMock = 3.x;` and `expectLastCall` is not required.

Answer (score 16):

This problem does not happens if you use the 'nice' API:

```
DBMapper dbmapper = EasyMock.createNiceMock(DBMapper.class);
```

There are two kinds of mock - strict and nice. The strict mock throws Assertion Error in case an unexpected method is called. The nice mock allows unexpected method calls on the mock.

For further details, refer to the official doc - http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-strict